# Google script to copy and rename a sheet and name is based on a cell reference

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google scripts and I need to copy the current active sheet to a new sheet and then rename this sheet based on a cell value. My issue is the cell value is a date and the below code works but instead on renaming the sheet 30-May-2014 it is returning the numeric equivalent 41789. How can I paste the actual date.

```
function CreateNewTimesheet() {

  // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

  // The code below will rename the active sheet to Month End date based on cell O3
 var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("O3").getValue();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need to format the value into a string and then use it to set the name.

```js
var localTimeZone = "Europe/London";
var dateFormatForFileNameString = "yyyy-MM-dd'at'HH:mm:ss";

function CreateNewTimesheet() {

  // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();

  // The code below will rename the active sheet to Month End date based on cell O3
 var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("O3").getValue();
 var dateString = getDateString_(myValue);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(dateString);
}

//Function to get Date as a string
function getDateString_(dateValue) {
      return Utilities.formatDate(dateValue, localTimeZone,
                                  dateFormatForFileNameString);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a new Date(myValue), then look in the Utilities class for the date formatting function.

Comment: I've made the following changes, and the sheet is being renamed in a date format but its a different date. Cell is displayed as 30 May 2014. The sheet is being renamed 2014-05-08. What am I doing wrong?     function CreateNewTimesheet() {
   
 // The code below will rename the active sheet to Month End date based on cell O3
 var myValue = new Date(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("O3").getValue);
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(formattedDate);
}

Comment: read on the web about date formats. you are using "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 0):

Just using .getDisplayValue() in place of .getValue() in your code should do the trick.

It gets the value displayed in the cell as a string, taking into account things like date formatting, so when you then use that to rename your sheet the sheet name will be the same as what you see in your cell.