# connect to mariadb using google scripts,error:Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol

Tags: google-apps-script, mariadb

I am using codes from [GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to connect to mariadb remotely with correct parameters.

```
    // Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var rootPwd = 'root_password';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var root = 'root';
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

// Create a new database within a Cloud SQL instance.
function createDatabase() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(instanceUrl, root, rootPwd);
  conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + db);
}
```

then I got the error: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

it seems that i cannot connect to Mariadb, I don't know what's the connection problem.

Comment: What php version do you use ?

Comment: I think this question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901948/automate-google-spreadsheet-data-load-from-external-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate Google Spreadsheet data load from external database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901948/automate-google-spreadsheet-data-load-from-external-database)

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariadb is not supported.

[From documentation:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)

> In Apps Script, the JDBC service supports Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.

If you want to use Mariadb with Google Apps Script, you will need to [write a REST API layer yourself, so that you can make simple UrlFetch calls from Apps Script to your db](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36752790#comment26). That comment links to the [postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) GitHub repository as an example of a REST API.