# Connect to postgresql database using google apps script from google spreadsheet

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've seen this question asked a few times before, most notably this StackOverflow question: [Automate Google Spreadsheet data load from external database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901948/automate-google-spreadsheet-data-load-from-external-database)

and here on Google issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36752790

but I'm looking for a more up-to-date answer.

I have a cloud-SQL instance of a PostgreSQL database running on GCP. I would like to automatically connect to it and populate a spreadsheet on a daily basis, which is possible for MySQL databases.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#java) on Google say to use a jdbc socket factory to connect to a PostgreSQL db using the format:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://google/<DBNAME>?"
"socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory"
"&socketFactoryArg=<InstanceName>"
```

I've also tried the format (slightly different) from the Google GitHub page (linked under the example in the docs):

```
"jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>"
```

After creating a url I run:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl)
```

But get this error:

> Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

I'm wondering if this is possible yet or if it is user error?

Comment: That issue tracker was last meaningfully edited just back in May, when it was reopened, so I think it's still the most up to date information.

Comment: Not sure it's possible. I've seen this article which let me think it's not covered 
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/postgresql-odbc-mysql-apps-script.rst

Answer (score 2):

I found JDBC in Google Sheets, especially for Postgres, to be buggy, so I built [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io/?ref=so) which lets you automatically send data from Postgres to Sheets. You can also also sync changes from Sheets back to a database and schedule refreshes daily, hourly or every five minutes.

Disclaimer: I built this.