# Duplicate Sheets daily

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a script that can duplicate a tab or sheet on a daily basis and rename that sheet with todays date.

I am sure this is possible but I can not find the answer anywhere.
The script I have so far is below, however it does not work and I cant get the right tweek to make it work.

```
function CreateNewPulseSheet() {

  // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master do not use");
  SpreadsheetApp .getSheetByName().duplicateActiveSheet();

  // The code below will rename the active sheet to a date based on cell M1 of the source spreadsheet

 var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M1").getDisplayValue();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google script to copy and rename a sheet and name is based on a cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472440/google-script-to-copy-and-rename-a-sheet-and-name-is-based-on-a-cell-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nearly identical to the question linked in Rubén's comment above. But to answer the question of what's wrong with this code, the line where you duplicate the sheet is the problem. You have a space after SpreadsheetApp, and then you call getSheetByName(), which returns a Sheet object. The Sheet object doesn't have a method duplicateActiveSheet().
What you want to do is this:

```
function CreateNewPulseSheet() {
  // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master do not use").activate(); //getSheetByName returns a Sheet, but doesn't set it as active
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet(); /Duplicate makes a copy and sets it as the active sheet

  // The code below will rename the active sheet to a date based on cell M1 of the source spreadsheet
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M1").getDisplayValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
}
```

I took out the sheet variable, because you never referenced it after declaring it.

Comment: Thank you, I have used your edit and i works perfectly,

Comment: Your script notes are contradictory. When you make a sheet active, it does in fact make it active.