# Google script to duplicate tab with data based on each row of existing sheet

Tags: google-sheets

So I am working on a [Payroll sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6nf-mtLSttmc13hCFD7hzsv3crGGive31ICsFoFkpo/), and would like the ability to automate generating paystubs. I have a overview sheet that has each week's pay and deductions on separate rows, one row for each pay period. I then have a paystub template that takes a work week input (cell O3) and fills data from a single row.

What I am looking for is the ability to on demand duplicate the template, and have it autofill column O3 with a specific work week. Like a for loop that can create say 52 copies, each one with a unique name (i.e. Paystub_WW01), and a different sequential value in O3. I've started messing a round with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472440/google-script-to-copy-and-rename-a-sheet-and-name-is-based-on-a-cell-reference).

Comment: After fiddling, I set up a "template" paystub that only has a single column that needs to be updated with the work week located at O3. I used that SUM formula for the year-to-date totals, so no need to worry about writing values. I guess duplicating the template and manually entering the work week each week isn't that hard, but I'm still curious how to write a script to perform this same function.

Comment: It's really challenging to parse this big paragraph and try to figure out exactly what you're asking. (Visuals help a lot!) You just want the work week automatically filled in?

Comment: I've cleared the block of text and tried to rephrase what I'm looking for a bit more concise. Just want to duplicate a template multiple times, with each iteration having a unique name and a specific cell value filled. For range Weekly!B3:B14, it would create 12 sheets with unique names, and cell O3 of the duplicates would be filled in with the corresponding BX cell for each iteration.

Comment: Edit in your code so far and we can help you from there. Also, a screenshot of your template paystub, rather than a link to the document, is highly preferred as your document may change, be deleted, etc., and thus not be helpful to future readers.

Comment: I literally have no more code than what is at that link. I don't know how to loop or create multiple pages based on entries in another sheet, and I don't know how to fill a cell using the script. I'm still looking into it, but open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with and it works:

```
function CreateNewPaystub() {

  //var declaration
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('PayStub_Template');
  var workweekRange = ss.getRange("Weekly!B3:B14");
  var workweekObjects = workweekRange.getValues();

  //loop through all work weeks to create duplicate tempaltes
  for (var i = 0; i < workweekObjects.length; i++) {

    // The code below makes a duplicate of the active sheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Paystub_WW' + workweekObjects[i]);

      //check if it exists
      if (sheet) {
         Logger.log("Sheet " + workweekObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {
           template.copyTo(ss).setName('Paystub_WW' + workweekObjects[i]);
           ss.getSheetByName('Paystub_WW' + workweekObjects[i]).getRange('O3').setValue(workweekObjects[i]);
           }
        }
  return;  
}
```